# Are ripe tomatoes that much better for making catsup vs red but not as ripe

Tags: tomatoes

Cooking a “less ripe” tomato increases the sugar taste of the tomato so do I need very ripe tomatoes for the best homemade catsup?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Unripe tomatoes are less sweet and generally more tart than ripe ones.

Comment: That’s my answer then. I thought heat improved the sugar enough to compensate. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what you mean that the heat improves sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Most ketchup/catsup recipes I see call for "ripe" tomatoes, so be sure they are fully ripe.  More importantly, these recipes tend to call for paste tomatoes (Roma, for example), which thed to be meatier and have fewer seeds. So, if you are looking to make the best quality product, the suggestion appears to be ripe, paste-variety tomatoes.